# Symfony 2.8 twig and bootstrap

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, bootstrapping

Is there a link or post about how Symfony can work with Bootstrap?
Not only forms but the general layout.

Maybe calling them in `resources:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Symfony Demo application](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo) uses Bootstrap and modern Symfony practices. Maybe you can check out its source code and file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately Symfony use Twig so you can extend templates and create macros for modal, panel, etc. You can even use Twig to generate dynamic javascript.

see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation,
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html